# How to create a one time registration page in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement, in which I need to create a dynamic signup page for my users. The idea is like, we create a signup page automatically and send it via email to a subscriber. After the subscriber registers through the link we need to make the link inactive/delete. This is to disable further registrations from the provided link.

I googled the idea but haven't got any useful insights on the topic. I will comment further details once anybody provide feedback to this thread.

Comment: So you are basically asking people here to develop your website? Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: You can do it by hash value , Different hash key will generate for each member and when user complete their signup process you can inctive the hash key for that particular user.

Comment: @KobyDouek: I think you have misunderstood my intentions. I have completed the website and its the final requirement and I haven't tried it yet because I don't know where to start at this point. I haven't asked for any source code, just some insights beforehand. I don't think people in stack overflow are generous enough to develop my website.

Comment: @PritamKarmakar: Thank you. I have some intentions on using hash or ref IDs. Do you have any threads available on this particular scenario ?

Comment: No. If you need any help just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

simple idea is to pass a linkid in the url as query string and  in database table create a bit column isVisited or somewhat ...when the user visit the link first check if the isVisited  column is 0 if is 0 then set it to 1 and if its already 1 means its visited once

Comment: What would be the type of the id??If its a numeric or Alphanumeric value then anyone could manipulate the Linkid by changing the linkid.

Comment: Thanks, I am planning to do so. Any way currently my reputation doesn't allow me to upvote your answer. Apologies

Comment: @PritamKarmakar its on you you can generate any type i would recommend string and in db make the column as uniqueidentifier